Spring boot: HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException for pdf download
In my Spring boot project, I created an endpoint to download a pdf file which is like this:
@GetMapping(value = "/file", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdfFile(@PathVariable final String contractId, @RequestParam final String generationId,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {
    final byte[] byteArrayPdf = this.pdfService.getPdfGenerationFile(generationId);

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    final String fileName = "mypdf.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(byteArrayPdf);
}

When I try to test it using Bruno, I have this exception:
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:249)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:428)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1332)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1143)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)

I do not understand why because the "Accept" is set to "application/pdf" for the request.
Can you help me to understand what is happening please?
Edit: By removing the "consumes" as suggested by @Nguyen Manh Cuong and changing method content to this, it works:
@GetMapping(value = "/file", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public void getPdfFile(@PathVariable final String contractId, @RequestParam final String generationId,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {
    final byte[] byteArrayPdf = this.pdfService.getPdfGenerationFile(generationId);

    try {
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=myPdf.pdf");
        response.getOutputStream().write(byteArrayPdf);
    } catch (final IOException ex) {
        // log and throw exception
    }
}

I do not understand the difference and why this solution works.

Because of consumes is the type which client send to server, Your method is GET, so it will HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException or HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.
Simply solution is to remove consumes:
@GetMapping(value = "/file",  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdfFile(@PathVariable final String contractId, @RequestParam final String generationId,
                                         final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

    final byte[] byteArrayPdf = this.pdfService.getPdfGenerationFile(generationId);

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    final String fileName = "mypdf.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(byteArrayPdf);
}


I have the same error with only produces. By changing the content of the method by setting content type, header and outputstream in HttpServletResponse object directly (no use of ResponseEntity) it works.

@phildeg31, I was copy your code to new project and run it, api sent by POSTMAN, no issue. Maybe the error in Bruno or your pdfService.

try final byte[] byteArrayPdf = new byte[0]

I have the same error. I edited my question with an other way I found that works but I do not understand the difference and why this solution works.
